# SignalR Owin logging

Tags: wpf, logging, signalr, owin, system.diagnostics

I've seen a couple articles and questions about this but nothing seems to work for me.

I've got a SignalR server hosted in a DLL that's then used in a WPF application. Generally, everything is working fine. But to make debugging easier I want some server-side logging. I have tried implementing [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing#enabling-tracing-on-the-server).

I wan't to use my own TraceListener (either way, I can't get any results with the TextWriterTraceListener either...), so this is what I've added to the configuration-tag in my app.config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="SignalR.SqlMessageBus">
      <listeners>
        <add name="SignalR-Bus" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="SignalR.ServiceBusMessageBus">
      <listeners>
        <add name="SignalR-Bus" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="SignalR.RedisMessageBus">
      <listeners>
        <add name="SignalR-Bus" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="SignalR.ScaleoutMessageBus">
      <listeners>
        <add name="SignalR-Bus" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport">
      <listeners>
        <add name="SignalR-Transports" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport">
      <listeners>
        <add name="SignalR-Transports" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="SignalR.Transports.ForeverFrameTransport">
      <listeners>
        <add name="SignalR-Transports" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="SignalR.Transports.LongPollingTransport">
      <listeners>
        <add name="SignalR-Transports" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat">
      <listeners>
        <add name="SignalR-Transports" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="SignalR.ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider">
      <listeners>
        <add name="SignalR-Init" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>

  <!-- Sets the trace verbosity level -->
  <switches>
    <add name="SignalRSwitch" value="Verbose" />
  </switches>

  <!-- Specifies the trace writer for output -->
  <sharedListeners>
    <!-- Listener for transport events -->
    <add name="SignalR-Transports" type="MyNamespace.MyListener, MyAssembly, Version=9999.0.0.17, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <!-- Listener for scaleout provider events -->
    <add name="SignalR-Bus" type="MyNamespace.MyListener, MyAssembly, Version=9999.0.0.17, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <!-- Listener for hub discovery events -->
    <add name="SignalR-Init" type="MyNamespace.MyListener, MyAssembly, Version=9999.0.0.17, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  </sharedListeners>

  <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
```

As I said, nothing happens when I use The TextWriterTraceListener and using my own class it doesn't even try to call the constructor or one of the methods.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no issue in Config and it works without any changes in sample.
I'll suggest to check Immediate window or Output window of visual studio sometimes trace channels are writing  to this windows. 
TextWriterTraceListener will simply create file at executing assembly path , please verify it is correct one.